# @types/serialport module not import into ts class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have installed this [dependency(js)](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport) in existing Angular(ts) project but you won't compile this code until if it's converted into ts. Then I found a ts supported [repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/serialport) that can manage your back support for typescript . But anyhow I am not able to import those dependency in my class

```
 import { SerialPort } from '@types/serialport';
```

And throw an error
**node_modules/@types/serialport/index"' has no exported member 'SerialPort'.**

So any other way can I import **serialport** object ? Please give a flag exactly where I am doing wrong. Your help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`Serialport` type declarations are from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/serialport).

From [the index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/serialport/index.d.ts), it seems to declare a namespace.

Try:

```
import * as SerialPort  from 'serialport';
```

**NOTE**: You directly import from `serialport` not from `@types`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years, and `serialport` has been updated (currently version 10.x.x). Now it has native typings, and you can use

```js
import { SerialPort } from 'serialport';
```

to import the module. You no longer need `@types/serialport`.